# Display favicon across entire domain with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, favicon

I am working on a web-app in node that allows image uploads. People can then generate links such as https://website.com/WRsdfFF23.jpg which takes them to the image however on this page the favicon of the site isn't shown. Is there something for node that allows me to display the icon across the entire app including the links that just show an image in the browser?

At the moment in my development environment I am accessing it as localhost:3000 and subsequently an image as localhost:3000/WRsdfFF23.jpg.

Thank you.

Edit 1:
I have also tried with favicon middleware "serve-favicon".

```
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'assets', 'favicon.ico')))
```

Comment: Why not place `favicon.ico` in the root directory, in that way all pages on the website will look for the favicon at `/favicon.ico` unless the HTML has decided to use another image as the favicon.

Comment: Ah, I could do that I think. I tried to but it is stil not showing at the moment but I may have this wrong. So my structure is something like

-Main
--assets
---favicon.ico
-index.html

Is this right? With my server side doing this: 

`app.use(express.static(path.join(mainDir, 'assets')));`

Comment: As long as the `index.html` is served at `/` I don't think the location of the file in your project matters. 

What you see when you type `example.com/favicon.ico`, does the icon show up?

Comment: When I point to example.com/favicon.ico the favicon is shown. I think this may not just show because of the fact that it is in a development environment. I have read from a few sources that localhost:3000 will sometimes not display the favicon but when in production the domain will cache in browser and will serve it from there on out.